# mongodb nodejs update using previous value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoDB database and have restructured how I store my date/times.
However I would like to update any old documents that are not stored in this format.

Using NodeJS how could I use the previous value of a field and update it using its previous value.

I'm looking for something along the lines of:

```
function modifyDateFormat(oldDate){...}

let filter = {}
let update = {
  $set: {date_time: modifyDateFormat(previousValue)}
}

db.collection("collection").updateMany(filter, update)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find the old document, then update using data from this document. No other way.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, first of all, you need to find all of them. Then you can work on that items and whatever you want.
To dig deeper [have a look](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-use-a-sql-like-statement-in-mongodb/).